# Dynamic CRM Plugin download Word document

Tags: c#-4.0, plugins, ms-word, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created CRM plugin, which on Case create need to download a document to the client. When I create a case plugin is working but it doesnt download a document. 
In console i can see a content of document is returned through POST request
..AppWebServices/InlineEditWebService.asmx but not opened or downloaded.

Im new in this so I will be a very thankful on any help. My code is bellow:

My code is bellow:

```
protected void ExecutePreValidateCaseCreate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
if (localContext == null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
}
String FileName = "Test.docx";
String FilePath = @"C:\Template\temp\Test.docx"; 

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tweaking the HttpResponse in a plugin is not supported and should be avoided by all means. In other words, you cannot do this using a plugin.

When you need to offer a download option in Dynamics CRM for (Word) documents, a solution could be to create a separate web site containing a download page. Then you can integrate this page into CRM by means of an IFrame or HTML web resource.

Comment: I thought it is not possible on this way...I'll try it with IFrame or HTML (Although I have not worked with it so far)...thanks for your reply

Comment: Could I call that Html web resource throught a CRM plugin, and pass to web resource a location of file to download?? is it possible?

Comment: It is more likely to call the plug in from the web resource, you could store the link in a hidden field inside your form, and load it into the web web resource, but that would require the form to be open so you can trigger the execution and then refreshed, since the changes made by the plug in to the record are not immediately available.

Comment: hmm...thanks for replay,but i think its not a solutions for me, because I need to create a document in plugin and that document download...since i cant download a document throught plugin, i thought, to create a web resource (JS) and after creating a document in plugin call that resource and pass them a location of document, and download with JS...thats my some idea..i dont even know it is possible?