# CRM 2013 C# Plugin fill Word template

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-word, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Im trying to create CRM plugin which will open Word template, fill it with data and download it to the user. This all work fine, except when I need to download document to the user. I know its not possible download it throught HttpResponse, so I dont know how I will tackle this.

Do you have any suggestion??

NOTE: here [Dynamic CRM Plugin download Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889029/dynamic-crm-plugin-download-word-document?lq=1) is the similar problem, which didnt solve the problem ,just sayed that is not possible throught HttpRequest.Response.

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamic CRM Plugin download Word document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889029/dynamic-crm-plugin-download-word-document). Please, do not register duplicate questions, but add a comment to your previous one.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, his previous question which was asked and answered related to the `HttpRequest.Response` stream. Since that was answered as not possible he is asking a new question about how to deliver a document from a Plugin.

Comment: Thank you @Nicknow for your explanation...@HenkVanBoeijen, I belive this is two totaly different questions

Comment: Since your latest question about triggering HTML/JS will also be a dead end I suggest taking this question further. Understanding from your different questions, I think I can come up with possible solution.

Comment: Since I dont have more idea how to solve this..I will be a very thankful you to help me...here or there, its all the same :)

Comment: how do you fill it with data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only means for plugins to "communicate" with users is an Exception (obviously, we don't want that!), my preferred approach in these cases is to create an `annotation` (a Note) attached to the record which triggered the plugin, attaching the file to it.

You'd then be able to download the file via JS through OData/FetchXml.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how far you already mastered creating your word document from a template, but I think the best way to achieve this would be to have a report create it for you.

With creating the doc out of the way, you can now simply [open the Report from a custom Ribbon Button as described by Jason Lattimer](http://jlattimer.blogspot.de/2014/09/running-report-from-ribbon-button.html).

If you still have the need to perform any special processing only possible in your Plugin before returing the doc, you could replace the standard "Save" Button by your custom Button.

Crm 2011 is limiting your options - if you'd be on Crm 2013 or 2015 things would be a lot easier.

Comment: im sorry for not responding...how is it easier in 2013?? since my question is posted, my crm is upgraded to CRM 2013 Service Pack 1.

Comment: In CRM 2013 and later, you can use synchronous Actions. This will allow you to interact with Custom Workflows developed in C# from JS Form scripting. In your case, you can seamlessly trigger an Action containing your Custom Workflow component and use the result (Word doc) o completion.

Comment: Thank you for your replay..I tried it with Reports, and saw in crm is a little options to work with reports,and access to data throught report,and its not possible to solve my problem with reports...Also looked for synchronous Actions, and not even sure how it will work, and could it solve my problem,since it need to return a document

Comment: It will take a little time to put together an answer with all the parts need to get a fully working solution. If you are having trouble with creating a custom report returning a word doc you can still create it in a Custom Workflow component. I'd suggest you take a look at Actions in CRM 2013 which basically are created like CRM Workflows (Processes) to understand the possibilities they offer.