# Call Web resource (Html/JS) from CRM plugin?

Tags: html, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I want when some code in plugin execute, then call or trigger on some way a web resource, so is it even possible and how I can call it?

NOTE: its important that first execute a plugin and then web resource!

Comment: This is not possible. A plugin cannot provide the form context a Html/JS web resource needs. If you'd describe the big picture maybe there's an alternative for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: here is my original problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889029/dynamic-crm-plugin-download-word-document/30890854#30890854...I need to create a document in plugin and that document download...since i cant download a document throught plugin, i thought, to create a web resource (JS) and after creating a document in plugin call that resource and pass them a location of document, and download with JS.

Comment: Okay, I see what your goal is: My approach would be to create the document in your (synchronous, PreCreate stage) Plugin, attach it as a Note to your Case/Incident and on switching your Form from Create-State to Edit-State you could have your JS offer the attached doc for download.

Comment: Actually this plugin will be on update case not on create as I thought earlier...I'm sorry, but im really new in this, so I dont understand how you thought "switching your Form from Create-State to Edit-State you could have your JS offer the attached doc for download"??

Answer (score 1):

A plugin cannot directly communicate with form script. However communication can be achieved through the data model. Based on your comments, I would suggest the following approach.

1. Create a plugin to create and store the document against the case record. (Perhaps set a flag field on the case to indicate the document is available).
2. In your web resource have JavaScript which queries CRM using OData to see if the document is available (perhaps based on the flag field). Then provide the document for download. You may also need to make some consideration around when to offer the download, as form script will run every time the form is loaded, constantly offering the document for download could be annoying for the user.

Alternatively, just do step 1. Then the user can download the document manually like every other attachment. If you have a flag field its easy to show a message that the document is ready.